# Programmatically checking if a site collection already exists before creating a new one.

Tags: site-collection, web-application

I have created a visual webpart that creates site collections programmatically. It works through SelfServiceCreateSite and does its job flawlessly but for one thing.

I need to check if the site collections that users are creating with the webpart already exist within the given webpart and I don't know how to do that. Is there anyone here that could give me some help?

I've read this blog, but I can't get it to work for me.

http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/code-snippet-how-to-check-if-sharepoint-site-collection-or-sub-site-exists/

Answer (score 2):

use

```
spsite.exists();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms428778(v=office.14).aspx

```
//if site doesnt exist
if (!SPSite.Exists("http://google.com"))
{
   //make site
}
```

if it doesnt like the above you might need to have the string as an actual uri like so:

```
//if site doesnt exist
Uri url = new Uri("http://google.com");
if (!SPSite.Exists(url))
{
        //make site
}
else
{
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style='color:Red'><p><strong>Sorry site already exists!</strong></p></div>"));
}
```

**EDIT**

just to clarify:

```
            Uri url = new Uri("http://google.com");
            if (!SPSite.Exists(url))
            {
                Console.Out.Write("site doesnt exists, create me");
                Console.Out.WriteLine();
                Console.Read();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Out.Write("site exists sorry you cant!");
                Console.Out.WriteLine();
                Console.Read();
            }
```

thats what i used to test and works just fine in a console app! I need to see some code to see where your going wrong, how your calling this code and whats going in within the if function! how your displaying the message!

Comment: I just keep getting the exception instead of getting the label that I put put out there to say "this site is already in use please pick another name".

Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The specified name is already in use. Please try again with a new name.

Comment: can you post some of the code to see whats going on? the code should work!

Comment: I would post code if I could get the formatting to swallow my code. I tried putting the code in <blink> in <html> ... What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, it works now I'm just slow. Thanks all the help you're a champion.

Comment: thats no probs happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the code in EventReceiver on FeatureActivating.